# web based remote desktop for connecting to android

Tags: java, php, android, html, web

Is there any code available (open source) that enables web based remote connection to an android device. ie logmein, pcanywhere type apps. I have seen this on a few apps on the market, but I need to add it to add to a project I am creating.

Just added. I am looking to control the android device, not android controlling remote pc.

Comment: And this for the client side maybe could help...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240633/web-based-vnc-client

Answer (score 1):

Note that a "remote connection to an android device" will require root to work, if you are aiming to support user input. Some will require a complete modded ROM.

You could search for VNC servers for Android, such as [Android VNC Server](http://code.google.com/p/android-vnc-server/) or [android-vnc](http://code.google.com/p/android-vnc/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this with ADB installed and your phone rooted.

http://code.google.com/p/android-vnc/